# Delete and insert into not working in SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-agent-job

I have a following transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ReadSalesFactsTransation;

BEGIN TRY

DELETE FROM  [dbo].[YSalesFacts];
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
INSERT [YSalesFacts] EXECUTE [ReadSalesFacts];


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

And i have added this command into SQL Server Agent and i am executing it as a TSQL Script and it'is not working. It executing like several 3 hours and i have an time out. But, if i run the same query in the Management (copy and paste and f5 to execute the command) it works like good.

In my procedurę is a few temp tables and many CTE, but it does work just fine in the Management Studio and not working with Agent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an open transaction in SQL mgmt studio that's blocking SQL agent from completing?

In another window run sp_who2 and see if your SQL agent connection is being blocked by another connection.

Comment: Yes, there is a lock when i am trying to execute in SQL Agent.

Comment: Right, so it's nothing to do with SQL agent and everything to do with whatever has the lock. Close that connection and problem solved.